# Git deployments with PHPloy using FTPS

Tags: php, git, ftp, ftps

I'm trying out [PHPloy](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy) for git deployments and I've run into a bit of a snag.

I've got the PHPloy.phar installed on my local machine, and have access to the phploy executable. I also have a phploy.ini file in the root of my project (below).

When I run phploy from the terminal, I'm getting the following error message:

> Warning: ftp_systype(): Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption. in phar:///usr/local/bin/phploy/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Ftp.php on line 453

**phploy.ini** (values for user, pass and host removed for this question)

```
[staging]
scheme = ftps
passive = true
user = username
; When connecting via SFTP, you can opt for password-based authentication:
pass = password
; Or private key-based authentication:
;   privkey = 'path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey'
host = hostname
path = /public_html
port = 21
; You can specify a branch to deploy from
branch = staging
```

FTP on this server is configured for TLS Explicit, but I'm not sure how / if I can specify that in the `phploy.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `.ini` file.

```
ssl = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying these:

```
scheme: sftp
port:22
```